# Powershell conundrum: how to compare to CSVs and pull matching data from each?

Tags: powershell, csv, compare

I've got a CSV file with a list of names in a "name" column.  In a second CSV I have a list of names in a "name" column, and also their employee IDs in an "employeeid" column.

My desired output is this: take the "name" column in CSV1, compare it to the "name" column in CSV2, and wherever there's a match, take the name from the "name" column of CSV1 *and* the matching employee ID in CSV2, and create a new CSV3 with a "name" column and corresponding "employeeid" column.

Here is an [image describing my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFonU.jpg)

I've started playing with import-csv to pull each CSV in as a variable, and also tinkered with piping that with select headers, but I don't understand the logic necessary to take username column matches between CSV1 and CSV2 and then combine that with employeeID from CSV2.

Thanks in advance for any guidance you can provide.

Brian

--
**Updated 3/19**

```
$csv1 = import-csv -Path "C:\csv1.csv" | select-object -ExpandProperty 'accountname' | Sort-Object | where {$_ -ne ""}
$csv2 = import-csv -Path "C:\csv2.csv" | select 'accountname','employeeid'

$accountNamesFromCSV2 = $csv2 | select-object -ExpandProperty accountname 
$compareTheTWo = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $csv1 -DifferenceObject $accountNamesFromCSV2 -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual -passThru
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have so far.

Comment: Also I would suggest looking at the Add-Member cmdlet

Comment: You have no code yet but here is the solution at a high level:
1.  Read CSV1 into powershell and create CSV1simple using only the name column
2.  Use compare-object to compare CSV1Simple to CSV2
3.  Use any matches to update CSV2 from CSV1

Comment: My approach to this would be to load CSV1 into an array, then match the name field from each record in CSV2 against CSV1, writing out the name and id fields into CSV3 if they match. The `-contains` operator should be useful here, and I suspect that the only cmdlets needed will be `Where-Object` and `Select-Object` (and the CSV cmdlets).

Answer (score 0):

It's friday so I'll be nice. To do it at the prompt:

```
$csv2 = import-csv .\bar.csv; Import-CSV .\foo.csv | %{$name1 = $_.name;$id = ($csv2 | ?{$_.Name -eq $name1}).EmployeeID; Add-Member -InputObject $_ -MemberType NoteProperty -Name EmployeeID -Value $id; $_} | select Name, EmployeeID | Export-CSV .\result.csv
```

Or, a little more human friendly version in a script:

```
$csv2 = Import-CSV .\bar.csv
$result = New-Object System.Collection.ArrayList
foreach($user in (Import-CSV .\foo.csv)){
    $id = ($csv2 | Where-Object{$_.Name -eq $user.Name).EmplyeeID
    Add-Member -InputObject $user -MemberType NoteProperty -Name EmployeeID -Value $id
    $result.Add($user) | Out-Null
}
$result | Export-CSV .\result.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks all for your input.  EBGreen, as I look through your human friendly version, I'm not seeing where a second CSV is pulled/compared?  I was thinking I'd need to do something like:
`$csv1 = import-csv c:\csv1
$csv2 = import-csv c:\csv2

$compare = Compare-Object $csv1.accountname $csv2.accountname -IncludeEqual | ? {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=="}`

And then some sort of loop to finish the compare:

`if ($compare) {

    foreach ($accountname in $compare.InputObject) {`

But again, my PS is weak...hence why I'm here :-)

Comment: Woops, that was a typo. I'll fix it

Comment: You definitely could do it through Compare-Object. Either way would work fine.

Comment: Thanks.  I banged on this some more today and updated the post to include my stab at code.  I believe at this point the $compareTheTWo variable shows me places in _both_ CSV files where there is an accountname match.  Now what I need to do is crawl through CSV2 and, wherever there is an accountname match, take the accountname _and_ its corresponding _ employeeid and dump to third .csv.  Am I close?

Comment: So, did you try what I posted? That should do what you asked or else I misunderstood what you were shooting for.

Comment: Ah sorry, I think I read yours too fast and didn't think it was pulling in a second CSV for comparison.  I'll give that a dance tomorrow when I'm back on the project and report back.  Thanks.

Comment: OK I believe the `user.Name` needs a closing brace, and then I think `System.Collection.ArrayList` should have an "s" at the end of Collections (are these both right)?   Then I get a ton of `Add-Member : Cannot add a member with the name "EmployeeID" because a member with that name already exists.`